# How to find the $E(N)$ using $E(M)$ where the $M$ and $N$ follow slightly different scenarios

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> An author sends his first manuscript to a large number of publishers, $C, D, E, ...$ , in turn, only
>   approaching each one, after the first, if the one before has refused it. There is a constant probability
>   $\frac{1}{4}$ that his manuscript will be accepted by each publisher approached. The random variable M is the 
>   number of publishers approached, up to and including the one who accepts the manuscript. Write down the values of $E(M)$ and $Var(M)$
>
> For his second manuscript the author decides to approach two other publishers, A then B, for each
>   of whom the probability of acceptance is $\frac{1}{2}$, before he approaches $C, D, E, ...$ . The probability of 
>   acceptance by each of these publishers remains $\frac{1}{4}$. The random variable N is the number of $A, B, C,
> D, E, ...$ approached, up to and including the one who accepts this manuscript. Write down the first
>   few terms of the series for $E(M)$ and for $E(N)$. By comparing corresponding terms, after the second,
>   and using your value for $E(M)$, find $E(N)$.

---

What  I did :

I got the first part correct.

For the first part, I realized that this is a Geometric distribution. So for a Geometric Distribution:

$$E(M)=\frac{1}{p}=4$$

$$Var(M)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}=12$$

---

**The problem is with this (second Manuscript), I wrote down the first few terms:**

**For M:**

$$\frac{1}{4} , \frac {3}{4}\frac{1}{4} , \frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4},...$$

**For N:**

$$\frac{1}{2} , \frac {1}{2}\frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4},...$$

---

*How to find $E(N)$ using this? I have no clue. Please help. They say by comparing, how can one find it by comparing?*

Comment: Here's a hint: If neither $A$ nor $B$ accepts the manuscript, we're back in the case of the first manuscript, but we've used up two tries.

Comment: @TedShifrin so that means $4+2=6$, but this is if they don't accept it. How can one say if they don't or what, and the expectation should be less in the second manuscript right? Thanks

Comment: Think about conditional probabilities here. You need to include the cases that $A$ or $B$ accepts the manuscript. Yes, the expectation is smaller in the second case.

Comment: @TedShifrin hmmmmmm

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do it in a somewhat different way that the one suggested.  If A accepts (probability $1/2$, then $N=1$. If A rejects but B accepts (probability $1/4$) then $N=2$. And if A and B both reject, then $N=M+2$, for we are back in the first scenario, except that we have gotten $2$ rejections already. The conditional expectation of $N$, given that there have been two rejections, is $E(M+2)$. It follows that
$$E(N)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2+\frac{1}{4}\cdot E(M+2).$$
We have $E(M+2)=E(M)+2$, and now we can use the answer for the first scenario to complete the calculation.

If you want to do it using series, write down the series for the **expectation** of $N$. You will see that the terms for $E(N)$ from $3$ on are closely related to the terms for $E(M)$. Multiply the $(k+2)$-th term by $4$, and subtract the $k$-th term of the series for $E(M)$. You will get a nice series.

**Remark:** We have done a conditional expectation calculation, in this case conditioning on the first two trial results. This kind of strategy is often useful.

Comment: In this case $E(N)>E(M)$ is that valid?

Comment: Andre :) Thanks. But I don't understand one thing, the second Expectation **must** be less the expectation in the first scenario...isn't it ?

Comment: The conditional expectation of $N$, **given** that A and B reject, is bigger than the expectation of $M$. But in the calculation from the displayed formula of the answer, we get $1/2+2/4+(1/4)(4+2)=2.5$. Substantially less than $4$, as you saw intuitively.

Comment: You are welcome. As I mention in the answer, you can do it with series, particularly now that you have the conditional expectation viewpoint. One can if one wishes (and I don't) remove all reference to conditional expectation and have a pure series argument.

Comment: Yep :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know a easy to understand good book for me to learn conditonal expectation and conditional probability? :)